# how to avoid duplicate entry in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, duplicates, laravel-7, laravel-validation

I want to give marks for each student for multiple subjects in different grades (10th,11th,12th) now i pick each student id and I can store marks for each student but i want to avoid duplicate entry for each grade and subjects. ***example if I give 50 marks in 10th grade for Math subject, again if i want to add marks for Math subject in 10th class, system should not accept and throw a message of duplicate entry.***
**NOTE: i am using Laravel 7**

here it is my MarkController store method:

public function store(Request $request)
{

```
    $this->validate($request, [

        'subject_id' => 'integer',
        'grade_id' => 'required',
        'final_marks' => 'required',

    ]);
    $getMarks = Mark::where('student_id',$request->student_id)->first();
         if($getMarks->subject_id != $request->subject_id ){
             if($getMarks->grade_id != $request->grade_id){
                 $marks = new Mark();
        $marks->student_id = request('student_id');
        $marks->subject_id = $request->subject_id;
        $marks->grade_id = $request->grade_id;
        $marks->final_marks = $request->final_marks;
        //dd('New Marks added');
        $marks->save();
             }

         }else{
             dd('duplicate entry');
         }
    return back()->with('marks-created-message', 'Marks added');
}
```

and this is my Marks table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('marks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('student_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('subject_id');
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger('grade_id');
        $table->double('final_marks',8,2);
        $table->timestamps();
    });


    Schema::table('marks', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students');
        $table->foreign('subject_id')->references('id')->on('subjects');
        $table->foreign('grade_id')->references('id')->on('grades');

    });
```

Comment: So you want `grade_id` and `final_marks` need to be unique?

Comment: @Espresso i need subject_id and grade_id to be unique once its entered. for the second time it should not allow to enter marks for same subject and grade.

Comment: Then you need to define one more custom rule

Answer (score 0):

From the code **subject** should be the only unique column because you can't assign grade without subject.
So the validation rule should look like:

```
$this->validate($request, [ 
    'subject_id' => 'integer|unique:marks', 
    'grade_id' => 'required', 
    'final_marks' => 'required', 
]);
```

Then if you need a customized message for duplicate entry then your validation should look like

```
$this->validate($request, [ 
    'subject_id' => 'integer|unique:marks', 
    'grade_id' => 'required', 
    'final_marks' => 'required', 
],[
   'subject_id.unique' => 'Duplicate are not allowed',
]);
```

You can get more info: [Form-request-validation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#form-request-validation)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding this logic in MarkController and it worked:

public function store(Request $request)
{

```
    $this->validate($request, [

        'subject_id' => 'integer',
        'grade_id' => 'required',
        'final_marks' => 'required',

    ]);
    $studentId = $request->student_id;
    $subjectId= $request->subject_id;
    $gradeId= $request->grade_id;
    $sub = 0; // declare variable
    $std =0; // declare variable
    $grd =0; // declare variable


    // Searching Record in DB
    $marks = DB::table('marks')->where('student_id', $studentId)->where('subject_id', $subjectId)
        ->where('grade_id', $gradeId)->get();
    //checking if record exist in DB
    if($marks) {
        foreach ($marks as $mark) {
            $sub = $mark->subject_id; // assigning vale to variable
            $std = $mark->student_id; // assigning vale to variable
            $grd = $mark->grade_id; // assigning vale to variable
        }
    }
    if ($sub == $subjectId and $std == $studentId and $grd == $gradeId){
        session()->flash('marks-duplicate-message','Marks already exist.');
     //   return redirect()->route('marks.store',compact('std'));
        return back();
    }else{
        $marks = Mark::create([
            'student_id' => $request->student_id,
            'subject_id' => $request->subject_id,
            'grade_id' => $request->grade_id,
            'final_marks' => $request->final_marks,
        ]);
        session()->flash('marks-created-message','Marks added.');
        return back();

    }

}
```