# Laravel API duplicated entry with multiple requests per second

Tags: php, laravel

I know that this topic has been widely covered on Stackoverflow, but none of the topics cover a public API.

[How to handle QueryException for duplicate entries in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893359/how-to-handle-queryexception-for-duplicate-entries-in-laravel)

[Laravel - Prevent multiple requests at the same time creating duplicate records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65441923/laravel-prevent-multiple-requests-at-the-same-time-creating-duplicate-records)

[how to avoid duplicate entry in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67392121/how-to-avoid-duplicate-entry-in-laravel)

I have a public Laravel API where users can create customers; items; invoices; and so on. The endpoints can be hitted several times per second and the developer may end up creating a miscalculated loop, which, sometimes, leads to the error

> #1062 - Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

The API is currently being used by dozens of entities and is expected to grow significantly. To prevent MySQL errors, I added a middleware that converts every endpoint into a DB transaction and commits if no error.

```
class CustomDBTransaction
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        $response = $next($request);

        if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200)
            DB::commit();
        else
            DB::rollBack();

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Then on `Kernel.php` I just appended the `CustomDBTransaction` middleware:

```
'api' => [
    'throttle:60,1',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CustomDBTransaction::class,
],
```

I have done a `Stress Test` on Postman and, indeed, the `Transaction` prevents errors on MySQL, but the endpoint is not executed properly, even if the data sent is perfectly formatted.

I believe that the `throttle` won't help here, because even with the limit of 60 requests per second, it may have a primary-key overlap if multiple users are accessing the API simultaneously.

What can I do mitigate the problem?

Comment: But `#1062 - Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'` must mean that you explicitly _specify_ the primary key value in your insert statements, no? Why would you do that, on the creation of _new_ records? Is your primary key _not_ an auto-increment integer?

Comment: @CBroe Actually no, this error was triggered on my MySQL Slave machine on a `logs` table insertion. My primary key is auto-increment integer, yes. I'd like to also point another example: I have a unique relation between two columns and to fill one of the columns I perform a query to grab the last number inserted (per entity) and add +1. If I perform a stress test on Postman, it will return a duplicated entry (on those unique fields) because the previous request as not yet been finish (meaning both fields will be duplicated).